# Binding SelectedPerson of Combobox to a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, datagrid

I'm currently learning to code, I'm new to wpf and databinding. I'm currently using caliburn micro for mvvm management.

The question:
I made a list of persons and made a bindablecollection of that list to fill up my combobox:

```
public List<Person> PersoonNamenList
        {
            get { return _persoonNamenList; }
            set
            {
                _persoonNamenList = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PersoonNamenList);
            }
        }
    public BindableCollection<Person> PersoonNamen
    {
        get { return _persoonNamen; }
        set
        {
            _persoonNamen = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PersoonNamen);
        }
    }
```

This is my view:

```
    <DataGrid
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" Margin="10,0,5,0"
        IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="Green"
        ItemsSource="{Binding test}"

        >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sport" Binding="{Binding Person.FullName,Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Beschrijving" Binding="{Binding ProgramBeschrijving}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duurtijd" Binding="{Binding ProgramDuurtijd }"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gewicht" Binding="{Binding ProgramGewicht}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Set" Binding="{Binding ProgramSet }"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Herhalingen" Binding="{Binding ProgramHerhalingen }"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

My SelectedPerson property for my combobox:

```
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }
        set
        {
            _selectedPerson = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PersoonNamen);
        }
    }
```

So as shown in the picture, when I select a person in the combobox I want certain properties to show in my datagrid (for example: First name, last name, Address). Don't mind the headers of my datagrid as they are test headers.I'm working with databasefirst EF.

Comment: Don't post images of code, paste your code directly into your question.

Comment: Thanks for telling me, I did an edit.

Comment: I believe your question is closely related to master-detail data display. check out this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-use-the-master-detail-pattern-with-hierarchical-data)

Answer (score 0):

If I right understood your scenario, the `Grid` will always have just one row displaying the Person's details.

This means that you have to add a new property of type `ObservableCollection<Person>` to your ViewModel that should be binded to `Grid` `ItemsSource` property. That property is the one that indicates which items show on the `Grid`. 
Following the XAML you posted, that property should be named `test`.

Supposing that the ViewModel binded to the `ComboBox` is the same binded to the `Grid`, you simply need to bind the property `SelectedItem` of your `ComboBox` to the property `SelectedPerson` you posted here in order to get the selected item of the `ComboBox` anytime it changes.
Every time this property changes you need to replace the existing item in the `test` collection to the one selected in the `ComboBox` and you have done.